# How to control differential chain rule in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a convolutional neural network with some layers in keras. The last layer in this network is a custom layer that is responsible for sorting some numbers those this layer gets from previous layer, then, the output of custom layer is sent for calculate loss function.

for this purpose (sorting) I use some operator in this layer such as K.argmax and K.gather.

In the back-propagation phase I get error from keras that says:

> An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval

that is **reasonable** cause the involvement of this layer in the derivation process.

Given that my custom layer do not need to corporate in differential chain rule, how can I control differential chain in keras? can I disable this process in custom layer?

Reorder layer that I used in my code is simply following:

```
def Reorder(args):
    z = args[0]
    l = args[1]
    index = K.tf.argmax(l, axis=1)
    return K.tf.gather(z, index)

Reorder_Layer = Lambda(Reorder, name='out_x')
pred_x = Reorder_Layer([z, op])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- It's impossible to train without a derivative, so, there is no solution if you want to train this model
- It's not necessary to "compile" if you are only going to predict, so you don't need custom derivation rules

If the problem is really in that layer, I suppose that `l` is computed by the model using trainable layers before it.

If you really want to try this, which doesn't seem a good idea, you can try a `l = keras.backend.stop_gradient(args[1])`. But this means that absolutely nothing will be trained from `l` until the beginning of the model. If this doesn't work, then you have to make all layers that produce `l` have `trainable=False` before compiling the model.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I wanna skip this layer for corporating in derivative process because this layer haven't any weight for updating in back-propagation. This layer operates as an wrapper that do some operation that don't need to learn to how do this process (for example sorting). Is it good idea that I define this as a layer in model or I have to do something else? any ideas? about trainable=false, I think this can not solve my problem because the gradient will be calculated whether trainable =false or not but this gradient will not update on weights when trainable=false

Comment: If you want weights to update before this layer, it's impossible to use this layer.